# Can we help someone remotely?

Tags: word-usage

Can I say "she cannot come in person to give me a hand with producing this journal but she is willing to help remotely"?

Is this fluent English?

Comment: It's grammatically and idiomatically sound. I wouldn't use the term 'fluent', which means "flowing easily" and is ordinarily used of speech rather than writing, and of longer passages than this.

Comment: thx. So a text may be sound but it cannot be fluent./how should I say a text is not only grammatically right but nice? rhetoric? @StoneyB

Comment: @StoneyB "is ordinarily used (of) speech rather than writing" Does of here equal (for)? very interesting. Can I use of instead of for everywhere after used?

Comment: @Juya 'use of speech' and 'and of longer...' means as a *part* it. And, no you cannot use it every time. The tool is used *for* cutting the grass and not *of*.

Comment: @Juya "is used of X" is a long-established idiom, abbreviating "is used **in speaking of X**", where *of* = *about*, so No, the usage cannot be generalized. It's rather old-fashioned and academic, but I am elderly and I used to be an academic. :)

Comment: @StoneyBI do need and want to make my written academic English perfect. Can you tell me what to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can say:

> *She cannot come in person and help me make/produce this journal, but she's willing to help remotely.*

That's *proper* English and not (preferably?) *fluent* as stated by StoneyB.

The [adverb remotely](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/remotely) is used to describe something *from a distance.*

> Remotely (adv.) - from a distance